# JAX-RS 2.0 jersey ready for project to be put into production in April-May?

Tags: jersey, jax-rs

I am building a RESTful web application in which I am interested to use asynchronous functionality and filtering. The application needs to be in production around April/May. Is it a good idea to start working on the available options for JAX-RS 2.0 Jersey since I cannot utilize this functionality in JAX-RS 1.0. If not then I might have to look into other options like Play Framework (which I am currently evaluating). I have seen that Resteasy 2.3.5 also has the required functionality but I was hoping to use the proper JAX-RS 2.0 implementation.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

if your app server is jboss 7.x I recomend you RESTEasy, Jboss people is responsible for RESTEasy and it's integrate with JBoss 7.x, the problem with RESTEasy and Jersey is **security**, please read about **OAuth** before you choose something, security is important, please implement this first, no only read, **implement it**

Comment: Yes, I have security as a top level priority and am looking into using OAuth or my own custom version for it. Nevertheless, I have not decided with the app server and hence I am open in that perspective. For now I was more inclined into Tomcat or Jetty with Jersey. RESTEasy is not a bad alternative either.

Nevertheless, this does not answer my main question. :)